# add a css file in webview

Tags: css, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I am having a web view . in that I want to call a css file. below coding I added a css file in web view but it's not showing any content.
my css file name is :style.css. first line of coding is in the style.css.

```
 p{color:#eadfa8},p a{color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}

NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"style" ofType:@"css"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

inside that file :

Answer (score 1):

Webview loads HTML code in it, so if you are applying CSS to your HTML code then following code will help you out. Just replace CSS code as you wish. It works perfectly for me:-

```
NSString* title;

title=@"Test CSS";

NSString* webViewBody;

webViewBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /><title>%@</title><style>body{font-family:\"Helvetica\";font-size: 12px;color: #343838; }body a{color: #343838;text-decoration: underline;} h1{ font-size: 15px;font-weight: bold;margin:0;padding: 0;}h2{ font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;margin:0;padding: 0;}.text{line-height:25px;text-align:justify;}@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) {#glink{width: 12%%;}} @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {#wrapper{ width: 75%%;}#googleMap{width: 100%%;}#glink{width: 22%%;}#details{width: 100%%;}#info{width: 100%%;}#broker{width: 80%%;}#contact{width: 80%%;}}@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {#wrapper{width: 75%%;}#googleMap{width: 100%%;}#glink{width: 18%%;}#details{width: 100%%;}#info{width: 100%%;}#broker{width: 80%%;}#contact{width: 80%%;}}@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {#wrapper{width: 50%%;}#googleMap{width: 80%%;}#name{width:60%%;}#details{width: 75%%;}#info{width: 75%%;}#broker{width: 80%%;}#contact{width: 80%%;}}</style></head><body><h1>MyHTMLBody</h2></body></html>",title];


 NSString *newWebViewBody = [webViewBody stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\u0153" withString:@""];

[webView loadHTMLString:newWebViewBody baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

First understand the purpose of the css, then try to use it. you won't see anything when you load css file to web view/browser. you can use the styles to display the HTML elements.

Comment: ya thank you bro.i am using a content in web view but the style is not changing bro.